# The case of the missing Maharsha (Sota 49, BK 82, M'nachos 64)

Tags: commentaries, tractate-sotah, maseches-menachos, bava-kamma, maharsha

There was fighting among the *Chashmonaim*, and one group besieged the other in Jerusalem, passing animals over the wall for the *korban tamid*, but eventually passing a pig.

This story is recounted (in greater detail than I've supplied) in three places in the *Talmud Bavli*:

- at the end of *Sota*, 49:2;
- *Bava Kama* 82:2, at the end of chapter "*M'ruba*"; and
- *M'nachos* 64:2.

The *Chidushe Agados* (of the *Maharsha*, in the back of the standard *shas*), explains the *g'mara*. He says

- in *Sota*, "The entire report is explained at the end of '*M'ruba*'";
- in "*M'ruba*" (*Bava Kama*), "See *Chidushe Agados* at the end of *Sota*"; and
- in *M'nachos*, "It's explained at the end of *Sota* and in '*M'ruba*'".

Um. (And the *mahadura basra* of the *Maharsha*, printed in the back of the standard *shas*, has nothing further.)

Is there an edition of *Chidushe Agados* in which he actually explains this *g'mara*, an edition which didn't make it into the standard *shas*?

If not, then, presumably, he erred, thinking he had written his *chidushim* in *Chidushe Agados*, but never doing so. (Or is there some other explanation for this state of affairs?) Did he write them elsewhere? — e.g., is a manuscript explanation of his for this *g'mara* available? Or perhaps one of his students wrote an explanation of this *g'mara*, quoting the *Maharsha*?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The Maharsha discusses the pig story in *Chidushei Agadot* at the end of Sotah, as advertised, but the comment is applied not to the [portion of the Gemara on 49b](https://www.sefaria.org/Sotah.49b.8-10?lang=bi) where the story is told, but [to the portion of the Mishna on 49a](https://www.sefaria.org/Sotah.49a.13?lang=bi&with=Chidushei%20Agadot&lang2=en) that that portion of Gemara comments on.

Here is the text of the relevant comment in the Maharsha:

> **בפולמוס** של טיטוס כו' פרש"י שהביא הורקנוס אאריסטובלוס אחיו כו' עכ"ל אבל התוס' פרק מרובה דחו זה דטיטוס בשעת חורבן היה כדאמרי' פ' הניזקין ומלכות בית חשמונאי קדמו טובא כדאמרינן פרק קמא דע"ז וי"ל דמעיקרא גזרו ולא קבלו כו' עכ"ל ע"ש ונראה עוד בזה שזה המעשה דבני בית חשמונאי שהביאו פולמוס של רומים על ירושלים היה התחלת וגרם החורבן שעברו הרומים הברית שהיה להן עם ישראל כדאיתא פ"ק דע"ז וכמ"ש בספר בן גוריון שע"י מריבת אלו אחי' בית חשמונאי באו חיל רומים על ירושלים וכבשוה והוא הרמז דלקמן בברייתא שנעץ החזיר צפרניו בחומה ונזדעזעה כו' שהחזיר מיער שהוא עשו יהיה שולט בחומת ירושלים ויזדעזע כל א"י על ידו ומש"ה מייתי הך עובדא דאחי' בית חשמונאי אפולמוס של טיטוס שהיה סוף החורבן ג"כ ע"י הרומים כחו של עשו וק"ל (פ' מרובה ע"ש):‏

The [*Chidushei Agadot* text available](https://www.sefaria.org/Chidushei_Agadot_on_Bava_Kamma.79b-82b?lang=bi) for the end of Chapter Meruba of Bava Kama doesn't appear to address this story. Maybe that section of whatever manuscript our version was based on got lost.

---

Thanks to [DoubleAA](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/759/double-aa) for discovering the location of the Maharsha's comment and reporting it in a comment on the question here.